# Accessing OneDrive in emulator

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to access files on OneDrive in the mobile emulator?

I have logged in as me in the emulator, but while on the device I get OneDrive listen in the Choose an App dialog, I can't get it to appear in the emulator.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to access files on OneDrive in the mobile emulator

Why not install the **OneDrive app** from Windows Store? On 14393 emulator, it works well:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer: you need to be logged into OneDrive (via app or via website) for OneDrive to be listed in the Choose App dialog.

Thanks